# React Native Hooks set initial date and then updated date

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, use-state

I'm trying to implement a date of birth funtionality that returns user's age. Now, the very first time user opens the app and heads to Edit Profile screen, i've set a default age of 18:

Edit Profile code:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now() - (9467880 * 60 * 1000)));
```

Now, when user edits age and then goes back to Profile page, the age is updated correctly in Profile screen. But when user taps on Edit Profile again, the age returns to default 18. How can i edit the hook to give it an initial value of 18 just for the very first time and then every time Edit Profile screen is opened again, show the updated value?
I would like to combine it with this hooks

```
const [date, setDate] = React.useState(route.params?.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `AsyncStorage`.

https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

```
const [date, setDate] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    if (!date)
      setDate(await AsyncStorage.getItem('date'));
    else 
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('date', date);
  })();
}, [date]);
```

Comment: thanks, and where can i add the 18 years old requirement? It doesn't work if i put the code snippet inside the useState -